# Sumarize colums to get just one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the result shown below, but I need to get only one row with the sum of the column QTD_PARC and VL_TIT, this in the SQl Server, can someone help me please?

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`?

Comment: Also, if you want us to improve your query, show us your query (as text, not as image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **sum()** with **group by** clause. If you want to calculate `mandt`, `nf_id`, `exercicio`, `num_tit`, `empresa`, `filial`, `ind_emit`, `desc_tit`, `ind_tit` wise sum of `qtd_parc` and `vl_tit` then you can select `mandt`, `nf_id`, `exercicio`, `num_tit`, `empresa`, `filial`, `ind_emit`, `desc_tit` and `ind_tit` along with `sum(qtd_parc)` and `sum(vl_tit)`
and you need to mention `mandt`, `nf_id`, `exercicio`, `num_tit`, `empresa`, `filial`, `ind_emit`, `desc _tit` (i.e., all the columns not included in an aggregate function like **sum**) in your group by clause:

```
 Select mandt,nf_id,exercicio,num_tit,empresa,filial,ind_emit,desc_tit, 
 ind_tit,sum(qtd_parc)qtd_parc,sum(vl_tit)vl_tit
 from MyTable
 group by mandt,nf_id,exercicio,num_tit,empresa,filial,
 ind_emit, desc_tit, ind_tit
```